# CSS styling is not being applied in my React application

Tags: css, reactjs

I am having this issue where the CSS code in my react app is not being run. The code compiles fine with no errors but it does not produce the correct styling.(The app is currently in development so there are some unused components)

[What it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyoka.png)

[What I get when the code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh61d.png)

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import { Navbar } from './Navbar';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
         <Navbar/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>Navbar</div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

App.css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body { 
  background: var(--color-bg);
}

a {
  color: unset;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gradient__bg {
  background:-moz-radial-gradient(circle at 3% 25%, rgba(0, 40, 83, 1) 0%, rgba(4, 12, 24, 1) 25%);

  /* safari 5.1+,chrome 10+ */
  background:-webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 3% 25%, rgba(0, 40, 83, 1) 0%, rgba(4, 12, 24, 1) 25%);

  /* opera 11.10+ */
  background:-o-radial-gradient(circle at 3% 25%, rgba(0, 40, 83, 1) 0%, rgba(4, 12, 24, 1) 25%);

  /* ie 10+ */
  background:-ms-radial-gradient(circle at 3% 25%, rgba(0, 40, 83, 1) 0%, rgba(4, 12, 24, 1) 25%);

  /* global 92%+ browsers support */
  background:radial-gradient(circle at 3% 25%, rgba(0, 40, 83, 1) 0%, rgba(4, 12, 24, 1) 25%);
}

.gradient__text {
  background: var(--gradient-text);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.section__padding {
  padding: 4rem 6rem;
}

.section__margin {
  margin: 4rem 6rem;
}

.scale-up-center {
    -webkit-animation: scale-up-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
    animation: scale-up-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
            transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale-up-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
            transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .section__padding {
    padding: 4rem;
  }

  .section__margin {
    margin: 4rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .section__padding {
    padding: 4rem 2rem;
  }

  .section__margin {
    margin: 4rem 2rem;
  } 
}
```

I have checked the developer tools on the website and no errors pop up and I have recompiled my code several times to try and get the CSS to work but the website just stays the same.